# Comparison of strings in Python

Tags: python, string-comparison

I need to compare two strings (direct and reversed), which are made of integer numgers. I try next code

```
str(1001) is str(1001)[::-1]
```

but it return `False`? Interesting, in IDLE output is the same/

Comment: Is checks to see if it is the same object, == checks for equality

Comment: You can get several useful results by pasting this question's exact title into a Google search. Please try that first in the future.

Comment: Use `==` for value comparison, not `is`.